# Can't access env variables inside cloudinary.config()

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables, cloudinary

When I put credentials for Cloudinary config as env variables, I get a server error. But if I directly type in the secret key and other credentials, it works fine. I have to use env variables because of security reasons. My env variables works fine in every other place. I have confined dotenv in the `app.tsx`.

.env:

```
NODE_ENV = development
PORT = 5000
CLOUDINARY_NAME = 
CLOUDINARY_KEY = 
CLOUDINARY_SECRET =
```

app.tsx:

```js
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import helmet from "helmet";
import connectDB from "./config/db";
import errorMiddleware from "./middlewares/errorMiddleware";
import generalRouter from "./routes/generalRoute";
import authRouter from "./routes/authRoute";
import cors from "cors";

dotenv.config({ path: __dirname + "/.env" });
connectDB();
const app = express();
app.use(
  helmet({
    crossOriginResourcePolicy: false,
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//Routes
app.use("/api/", generalRouter);
app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);
app.use(errorMiddleware);

export default app;
```

storage.tsx:

```js
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";
import { CloudinaryStorage } from "multer-storage-cloudinary";

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET,
  secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
});

const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary,
  params: <any>{
    folder: "ProfilePictures",
    allowedFormats: ["jpeg", "png", "jpg"],
  },
});

export default storage;
```

Comment: Hey, I'm one of the Developer Support Engineers over at Cloudinary.

Could you please provide the full error output in your post? Without being able to search your cloud name in our logs, it's difficult to pinpoint exactly where this might be going wrong.

What line endings is your .env file using? If your app.tsx uses Unix line endings and your .env uses Windows line endings, that may cause the env vars to be passed incorrectly.

If you'd like to discuss this privately, please feel free to [raise a support ticket](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) with us :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to how you are calling the `dotenv` module in your application.  According to the dotenv module [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), try this

```
const path = require('path')
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env') })
```

or

```
require('dotenv').config()
console.log(process.env) // remove this after you've confirmed it working
```